# Break on any thrown exception in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app in Xamarin forms in Visual Studio 2015. When I debug my app, I would like that it breaks on any thrown exception. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and check the "Break when thrown" box against Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

You may get a lot of noise this way though, as this will also break on exceptions thrown in libraries or inside the framework itself.